# How to generate token for api.partner.microsoft.com to access Price and Offer under Sell Menu in partner Center

Tags: azure, amazon-selling-partner-api

```
var cc = new ClientCredential(AppClientID, AppClientSecret);
var context = new AuthenticationContext("https://login.windows.net/common");
var result = await context.AcquireTokenAsync("https://api.partner.microsoft.com/", cc).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

**I want to call the below API**
[https://api.partner.microsoft.com/v1.0/sales/pricesheets(Market='All',PricesheetView='legacy_perpetual_software')/$value](https://api.partner.microsoft.com/v1.0/sales/pricesheets(Market=%27All%27,PricesheetView=%27legacy_perpetual_software%27)/$value)

[image]

Permission given to Azure Active Directory App as of below image.

[image]

**NOTE : The code is successfully generating the access token, but when I am using this token to call the API, I am getting 401 Unauthorized error.**

Comment: in exactly the same boat as you, exactly! DId you get any furthur on this?